# App crashed : Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, notifications, switch-statement

I'm working on an app that shows status bar notifications to the user. The user can turn on and off the notifications and the notification sound by 2 switches. I run the app and tried to switch on the notification and it crashed. The stack trace said on line 60(i marked it so that youcan find it easily):
*Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.NotificationManager.notify(int, android.app.Notification)' on a null object reference*

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import static android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity;
import static android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;


public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {
    Switch simpleswitch1;
    Switch simpleswitch2;
    private Notification notification;
    NotificationManager manager;
    Notification myNotication;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);


        simpleswitch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.simpleswitch1);
        simpleswitch2 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.simpleswitch2);
        simpleswitch1.setChecked(false);
        simpleswitch2.setChecked(false);
        simpleswitch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){{
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.rj.notitfications.SECACTIVITY");

                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Settings.this, 1, intent, 0);

                    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(Settings.this);

                    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
                    builder.setTicker("this is ticker text");
                    builder.setContentTitle("WhatsApp Notification");
                    builder.setContentText("You have a new message");
                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification);
                    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                    builder.setOngoing(true);
                    builder.setSubText("This is subtext...");
                    builder.setNumber(100);
                    builder.build();

                    myNotication = builder.getNotification();
                    manager.notify(11, myNotication);//THE ERROR LED HERE
            }


        }
                simpleswitch2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked){
                    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;




                }}






    });}});}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a crash is because you don't initialize the `manager` property. You can do it before you use `manager` like this:

```java
manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)
```